# Facebook serverside login, not working

Tags: java, php, ajax, facebook

Hi am regarding facebook php server side login..
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

in that

```
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
```

what is the meaning of this..., what is this code ?

Answer (score 0):

> Once the user has authorized your app, you should make a server side
>   request to exchange the code returned above for a user access token.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &code=CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK
```

Note the "CODE_GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK" comment.

$_REQUEST['code'] is most likely a token that guards against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). Facebook will create this and give it to your application via $_REQUEST['code'] (could be a POST, GET or whatever).

If you're not sure what $_REQUEST is, you should read the [PHP manual entry for it](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

Comment: But for the first time $code = $_REQUEST["code"];  giving error, as its requesting code first time from user, so do we need to give any default code.

Comment: i am using only one test.php and copied content bottom of this url..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565283/normal-servlet-login-program-with-google-facebook-login-in-tomcat-server#comment16927215_12565283

Answer (score 0):

$code is like authorization token that you exchange for an access token that you will use later to make calls to facebook api.  The part you're looking at handles redirect from facebook after user logged in to facebook and authorized your application to access their information.  at this point facebook redirects user back to your site and passes code as a get parameter and that line grabs that code from $_REQUEST, which in this context is the same as $_GET['code']